# Transform NULL into target column's default values in a INSERT INTO SELECT query

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to solve this problem without having to specify (and maintain) a statically typed column list in every query?

```
DECLARE @src TABLE (Id INT, Created DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @src
VALUES (1, NULL)

DECLARE @dst TABLE (Id INT, Created DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @dst
   SELECT *
   FROM @src
```

Error:

> Cannot insert the value `NULL` into column `'Created'`, table `'@dst'`; column does not allow nulls.

INSERT fails.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert default value when parameter is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230662/insert-default-value-when-parameter-is-null)

Comment: The error you are getting is simply because you have declared dst Created column as "NOT NULL" and you are trying to insert a NULL value from src. This is a bit of a red herring. Check my answer for a way to avoid typing a column list in every query.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you specify NOT NULL then? Default value is fired IF ONLY the column is not specified, that means that you are NOT INSERTING any value to that column. However in your case you are inserting NULL value to the table. If you would do:

```
insert into @dst(id) select id from @src
```

it would insert default constraint. You can use triggers to change the value to GETDATE() if NULL is inserted.

Comment: NULL is not a VALUE. It is a mark for absence of VALUE.

Comment: It is topic for long discussion. When you are inserting NULL to the row, you want to set the value of the row as NULL. I know what you are talking about  I just didn't know how to explain it in other words.

Answer (score 0):

With a static table definition and then a "Select *" to fill it, you have to be sure that the column ordering is correct and the table hasn't been modified in the meantime which could affect the results. It's fraught with danger and prone to issues. A better route would be to use SELECT INTO and a Temporary Table. The SELECT INTO will create the table schema if it hasn't been created before, thereby removing the need to declare one.

```
SELECT 1 AS [ID], CASE WHEN s.val IS NULL Then GETDATE() ELSE s.Val END as [Created Date]
INTO #src
FROM Source s

SELECT s.* 
INTO #dst d
from #src s
```

You can cast the values in the select statement to play around with the created temporary table columns types or Put Case statement logic in if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what you are trying but this works and since its table variable I don't think there is problem using it this way, I assumed more value

```
DECLARE @src TABLE (Id INT, Created DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @src VALUES (1, NULL)
INSERT INTO @src VALUES (1, '2015-01-01')

DECLARE @dst TABLE (Id INT, Created DATETIME NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @dst
SELECT s.Id,
       CASE WHEN s.Created IS NULL THEN GETDATE() ELSE s.Created END
FROM   @src s
```

SQLFidlle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/1367

Comment: Problem is that he select NULL from first table `@src` and then try explicit to insert NULL into `Created` column into second table

Comment: @veljasije can you see update, I guess I understood your comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
declare @src table (Id int, Created datetime)
insert into @src values(1, null)

declare @dst table (Id int, Created datetime default getdate() not null)
insert into @dst 
select 
    Id,
    COALESCE(Created, GETDATE())
from @src
```

So, if you insert some date in first table (column `Created`) and then execute second query, then second table will be populated with values from first table. If you, even, want to insert NULLs into first table, then in second query you must do some workaround to not allow explicit NULL to be written into second table (ie. `COALESCE`).

Of course, if you omit `Created` column in second query, then will be triggered `DEFAULT` constraint and it will insert `GETDATE()` value by itself.